# Is there any way to check who is subscribed to other Youtube channel?

Tags: youtube, gmail

I am searching on web, and i need to check users subscribed to other youtube channel, is there any way to get a list of all users who are subscribed to other Youtube channel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible (*as far as I know*) due to:

1. Some Youtube users has their subscriber count hidden, and
2. If this is not possible with Youtube data API or by web-scraping the *public* data, then, I'm afraid this cannot be done.