# Youtube API V3: Filter my subscribers by channels

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So I am building a web app whereby I want to check if certain channels (users) are subscribed to an certain (authed) channel via the API using the v3 Data API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

Obviously the subscriptions/list API has restrictions when trying to retrieve `mySubscribers=true` and it simply wouldn't be feasible for large channels. Also the number of users I want to check is dynamic, and so iterating over them and checking from their perspective (I have auth tokens) seems a little intensive.

What I have noticed is that the `forChannelId` filter works to filter a users subscriptions, but not for filtering a channels subscribers.

Is this possible at all?

Ideally the query:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&forChannelId=xxxxxxx%2Cyyyyyy&mySubscribers=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Would return the authed channels subscribers filtered by the `forChannelId` channels, the same way as the it does for subscriptions:

```
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&forChannelId=xxxxxxx%2Cyyyyyy&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Is there any alternative way to achieve such a check in a single bulk call, without having to loop over users I want to check and spending potentially unnecessary quota points?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, I don't think this is possible, to be honest. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72045107/12511801).

Comment: Thanks @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes but I'm not sure that's relevant, I am not trying to get the subscribers of another un-authed youtube channel, I am trying to get the subscribers to a fully authed channel, which I can do, but filtered by particular channels I want to search for. Enabling me to get around the shortcomings in the `mySubscribers` filter which will never return more than 1000 subscribers (50 at a time).